# Angular CLI: Can't bind to Property' sip' since it isn't a known property of 'img'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a small Angular2 CLI project where I display Sharepoint user with Lync Integration. In general web app, I give directly as following:

```html
  <span>
    <span class='ms-imnSpan'>
        <a href='#' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink' >
        <span class='ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10'>
            <img name='imnmark' title='' ShowOfflinePawn='1' class='ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-10x10x32' src='/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23' alt='User Presence' ([sip])='email' id='imn_{{userId}},type=sip' />
        </span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span>
        <a href='#' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink' tabIndex='-1'>
        <img name='imnmark' title='' ShowOfflinePawn='1' class=' ms-hide' src='/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23' alt='User Presence' ([sip])='email' id='imn_{{userId}}_2,type=sip' />{{userName}}</a>
    </span>
  </span>
```

If I use code like above my angular app giving error, sayinng can't bind to property 'sip' since it isn't a known property of 'img'. Really lost here couldn't find much information for such property bindings. Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: Why do you think there is as `sip` property?

Comment: I use this to show user presence from Lync. For that I need to have sip property for img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error with  ngAfterViewInit() call and I added sip attributes to img tag in this method. Here is my complete code for that:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('imnmark');
    for(let i=0; i< elements.length; i++) {
        var att = document.createAttribute("sip");      
        att.value = this.email;                          
        elements[i].setAttributeNode(att);

        var onloadAttr = document.createAttribute("onload");      
        onloadAttr.value = "IMNRC('"+this.email+"', this)";                          
            elements[i].setAttributeNode(onloadAttr);
    }

    if(typeof(window["IMNRC"]) != 'undefined') {
       window["IMNRC"](this.email, document.getElementById('imn_uniqueId,type=sip'));
       window["IMNRC"](this.email, document.getElementById('imn_uniqueId_2,type=sip'));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Angular2 syntax

```
([sip])='email'
```

It's called banana-in-a-box not box-in-a-banana ;-)

```
[(sip)]='email'
```

The `<img>` element doesn't have a `sip` property, therefore you probably mean

```
[attr.sip]='email'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That doesn't work. Here is my updated code: <img name='imnmark' title='' ShowOfflinePawn='1' class=' ms-hide' src='/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23' alt='User Presence' [(sip)]='email' id='imn_{{ownerUserId}}_2,type=sip' />{{userName}}</a>